# How to add the default values to the add_option in wp plugin

Tags: wordpress

```
function update_ptechsol_details(){

    register_setting( 'ptechsol_copyright', 'ptechsolcopy_link');
    register_setting( 'ptechsol_copyright', 'ptechsolcopy_name');
    register_setting( 'ptechsol_copyright', 'ptechsolcopy_default');
    register_setting( 'ptechsol_copyright', 'ptechsolcopy_year');
    register_setting( 'ptechsol_copyright', 'ptechsolcopy_text');
}

function copyright() { ?>
<p><em><center><?php echo get_option('ptechsolcopy_default') ?> <?php echo  the_date('Y');?> <a href="<?php echo get_option('ptechsolcopy_link'); ?>"><?php echo get_option('ptechsolcopy_name')  ?></a> All Rights Reserved.</em></p></center>
<?php }
add_action('wp_footer',copyright);
function copyright_admin_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <b>Pomegranate Technology Solutions Copyright Plugin</b>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php settings_fields( 'ptechsol_copyright' ); 
        global $ptechsolcopy_default;
        $ptechsolcopy_default= "Copyright &copy";

        ?>
        <?php if(function_exists(do_settings)){do_settings( 'ptechsol_copyright' );} ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="copyright_admin_setup" />
        <table class="form-table setup">
                <tr width="auto" >

                    <td width="auto">Copyright Injection By Default</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="ptechsolcopy_default" value="<?php echo get_option('ptechsolcopy_default');?>" disabled="disabled"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td width="auto">Year From:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="ptechsolcopy_year" value="<?php echo get_option('ptechsolcopy_year');?>"/> To: <?php echo Date('Y')?></td>  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td width="auto">Anchor Text</td> 
                    <td width="auto"><input type="text" name="ptechsolcopy_name" value="<?php echo get_option('ptechsolcopy_name');?>"/></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td width="auto">Anchor URL</td> 
                    <td width="auto">
                        <input type="text" name="ptechsolcopy_link" value="<?php echo get_option('ptechsolcopy_link'); ?>" />
                    </td></tr><tr>
                    <td width="auto">
                    Additional Text
                    </td><td><input type="text" name="ptechsolcopy_text" value="<?php echo get_option('ptechsolcopy_text'); ?>" /></td>

                </tr>
            </table>

            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php  

}



?>
```

Hi this is the above code for the copyright plugin that i created I need to know how to set the default values for the copyright injection by default. 
I want to set like

How can make default copyright when the plugin is activated ,What I did wrong with the code anyhelp would be great. I register the settings for My purpose .Even I tried the default values to the $ptechsolcopy_default= "Copyright&copy" and called back its working I need to make editable for the future preference any help would be fin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [plugin activation hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) to set the values you want when the plugin is activated. Add this to your plugin file to run the `set_up_options` function when your plugin is activated.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'set_up_options' );

function set_up_options(){
  add_option('name', 'value');
}
```